# Why Does C# Not Bind Correctly to Generic Overridden Methods?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-errors

I have defined the following classes and methods:

```
 using System;
 using System.Linq.Expressions;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 public class ReturnValue<T, S> {}

 public class Something<T>
 {
     // Sorry about the odd formatting. Trying to get it to fit nicely...
     public ReturnValue<T, C>
     Do<C, S>(C control, Expression<Func<C, S>> controlProperty)
     where C : Control
     {
         return new ReturnValue<T, C>();
     }

     public ReturnValue<T, ToolStripItem>
     Do<S>(ToolStripItem control, Expression<Func<ToolStripItem, S>> controlProperty)
     {
         return new ReturnValue<T, ToolStripItem>();
     }
 }
```

This compiles fine. Woo hoo! Half-way there. Then, I try to use it later with code like this:

```
 var toolStripItem = new ToolStripStatusLabel();

 var something = new Something<string>();
 something.Do(toolStripItem, t => t.Text); // Does not compile
```

This, however, dies with the following error message

> The type `ToolStripStatusLabel` cannot be used as type parameter `C` in the generic type or method `Something<T>.Do<C,S>(C, Expression<Func<C,S>>)`. There is no implicit reference conversion from `ToolStripStatusLabel` to `Control`.

It seems to me that the C# compiler has failed in this case though the two methods do not create a set of ambiguous method declarations. `Control` and `ToolStripStatusLabel` exist as siblings in the inheritance tree of `Component`. I would think that the compiler would have enough information to correctly bind the method invocation in the client code.

However, if I do the same thing with my own sibling classes, then everything compiles fine.

```
 public class Parent {}
 public class Child1 : Parent {}
 public class Child2 : Parent {}

 public class Something2<T>
 {
     public ReturnValue<T, C>
     Do<C, S>(C control, Expression<Func<C, S>> controlProperty)
     where C : Child1
     {
         return new ReturnValue<T, C>();
     }

     public ReturnValue<T, Child2>
     Do<S>(Child2 control, Expression<Func<Child2, S>> controlProperty)
     {
         return new ReturnValue<T, Child2>();
     }
 }

 var child2 = new Child2();
 var something2 = new Something2<string>();
 something2.Do(child2, c => c.GetType()); // Compiles just fine
```

Can anyone shed light on what I have done wrong, if anything?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the first method *is* in the candidate set for overload resolution, because the type constraint `C : Control` is only applied *after* overload resolution has been performed. I believe you're expecting it to be weeded out early - and it isn't.

Now, if you treat `C = ToolStripItem`, the first overload is more specific than the second - so the result of overload resolution is to pick that first version.

The type constraint validation is *then* applied... and fails.

I have a [blog post on this matter](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/10/28/overloading-and-generic-constraints.aspx) which may help you to understand the process, and then [another blog post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/11/02/evil-code-overload-resolution-workaround.aspx) where I apply the rules in a rather silly way.

EDIT: In your second example, the type of the argument is *exactly* the type specified in the first parameter, so the first method doesn't end up being more specific. The second method wins due to having fewer type parameters (I think; I haven't checked it in detail) and is then validated and passes.

To put it back into ToolStripItem terms, you could actually make your first sample compile  with one simple change:

```
// Change this
var toolStripItem = new ToolStripStatusLabel();
// To this...
ToolStripItem toolStripItem = new ToolStripStatusLabel();
```

Changing the compile-time type of `toolStripItem` from `ToolStripStatusLabel` to `ToolStripItem` takes away the "advantage" that the first method had, so it then compiles.

Comment: Jon, that's a great explanation. Thank you.

Comment: So why does the second example compile?

Comment: BlueRaja (besides a great name) writes correctly, which I thought about after considering the explanation further. Any insight, Jon?

Comment: @realistschuckle: See my edit. (I've just checked, and it does compile with the change.)

Comment: @BlueRaja: (Just in case you didn't see it before) Have a look at my edit.

Comment: @jon-skeet Thank you. You have an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to be more explicit with your call:

```
var toolStripItem = new ToolStripStatusLabel();
var something = new Something<string>();
something.Do<string>(toolStripItem, t => t.Text); // might compile
```